# Add A New Record Row To A Table Using A Form Click Button VBA Code

Tags: vba, ms-access

Im moving from Excel and starting to use MS Access to create my personal Comic Book database. I have been trying to create VBA code to add a new record to a table using a button when clicked. Im also trying to add a new row but it seems to be just changing the SAME record.

I have tried some methods from youtube tutorials but none seem to be using a button so im finding it difficult on how to integrate the button into the code to work together.

```
Private Sub cmdSaveNew_Click()
Dim R As Recordset

Set R = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [Issues]")

R.Addnew
R![Title] = Me.Title.Value
R.Update
R.Close
Set R = Nothing
DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using bound form and bound controls? If so, why do you need code to add a record?

Comment: i dont getting anything when using set warnings.

Comment: Im not using bound forms.

Answer (score 0):

Well it not so much that you want to add a new record (your posted code should do that).
The REAL issue is what do you want to do with the record you just added? And is this table (recordset) based on the current forms bound table?

Adding a new record  in code will not by magic cause the current forms record to change, or move, or jump to the current record you just added. So, it not "really" that you want to add a new row to a table, but how do you want or plan to edit the record you just added?

If you are using a form that is bound directly to the table Issues, then you would not need to use code to create a new row of data, but BETTER is to jump/force/move the current form to a new record that would allow you to then edit the data.

So, you could execute this:

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, , acNewRec
```

In the above, your current form would be sent to a new reocrd at which point you can now enter data into the form.

As for just adding a row to Issues? Well, the real issue is what/when/where/why you want to use that new row. If you run your example code, and then from Access UI open up tables, you should see a new row of data. But that begs the real question as to what then you want to do with that new row of data. combo boxes, or the current form you are editing will NOT become aware of that new row, nor will combo boxes.

So, the context of your goal here is EVERYTHING as to what approach you should and want to do. So, your code as posted should add a new row of data, but the current form, and controls will not be aware of or be able to use that new row of data until such time you note or explain what you want to occur next. So you can add a new row with your code, but REALLY what is the task at hand, and want do you want to do with that new row of data?

If you have a existing form, and say a combo box, and you want from the drop down to select a "issue", then of course driving the list of available selections for the combo box could be driven by the combo box to make ease of data entry easy. And if the issue choice you make is not in the combo box (that choices are driven by issues table), then you would use the combo box not in list event, and prompt the user "do you want to add?". And if the user hits yes, then you could run you code to add the one new "issue", and then that new issue would appear as a choice in the combo box.

So, the challenge in access is that you have so many choices to do a task, but until the actual task and workflow at hand is explained, then a tiny snip of code unlikely solve your probem, but worse not provide the actual solution that you are looking for.

This is "why" in the comments, people are asking why do you need code when bound forms in most cases can add the row of data, and do so without you have to write code to insert data into a table. But, then again, the given context here is that you wanting to add a new row of data, but it not clear if the form you are working on is bound to that table issues, or issues table is another separate table from the current form. So, for the current form and data bound table, you as a general rule don't need code to insert rows of data. And perhaps the issues table is a related child table to the current form + table. IN that case, then a sub form would be used, and again you don't have to write code to insert rows of data. So, is the issues table just driving a combo box? Or is the issues table bound and driving the data for the current form and all of its fields?

Comment: Thanks for your long message. I will try to answer your qeastion as best i can. I am very new to MS Access so im getting a bit lost on some of the things you are suggesting. What i am trying to do is be able to add/insert a New Record using A Form but with a Button and not using the small arrows at the bottom of the form. Of course in time i will also need to create a pop up Edit Form. This database is just a personal inventory for my Comic Books which i wanted to create as Excel spreadsheet is getting a bit bogged up now.

Comment: The code i posted does work. I just could not get it to work with a BUTTON.

Comment: Never mind i have sorted the problem. Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Comment: Ok, if you wanted a button on a form to "start" a new record, then use this behind the button: <<   DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec  >>. So its only one line of code behind the button, and no need to open a record-set, or use code to actually add the record. So, as noted, the context here is everything. So, to jump the form to a new record, then use the above command - it really much the same as if you used the navigation buttons (but, as noted, you can turn off and hide the navigation buttons if you want).